# openGL set perspective camera distance based on bounding box on an ellipsoidal model

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, geometry, openscenegraph

I have a perspective camera that i am using to look at a 3D scene consisting of the earth model. The earth model is ellipsoidal. I want to an overview on this model based on a certain bounding box on the model i.e. basically i want to do a simple 2D overview on this 3D model. I wanted  to calculate the camera distance for this.

[image: A simple diagram describing the same]
[image]

I am actually doing this in open scene graph so i can get an osg::BoundingBox for the desired scene/area.

I am using a very simple method to calculate the distance.

```
distanceVertical = ((boundingBox.yMax - boundingBox.ymin)/2.0)/ tan(fovy/2)
distanceHorizontal = ((boundingBox.xMax - boundingBox.xmin)/2.0)/ tan(fovx/2)

cameraDistance = max(distanceVertical, distanceHorizontal)
```

This calculation is all in world space but somehow it is not giving me the right distance. Am i calculating this wrong?

Comment: What distance is wrong? From the code you give and from what I can remember, distanceVertical should be giving you a correct value, assuming fovy is the radians version of what you give to your camera, while distanceHorizontal should be wrong.

Comment: Is your camera axis-aligned like your bounding box? What are the values for the setProjectionMatrixAsPerspective are you giving? What are the inputs and the results of your calculation and what are you expecting ("it is not giving me the right distance" is quite vague)?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt What i finally tried was 1) Generate a rotation matrix from (0,0,1) - z-axis to my bounding box center. 2) Rotate all eight corners of my original bounding box using this rotation matrix. 3) Compute a new bounding box by finding the min and max of x,y,z of these rotated points 4) cameraDistance1 = ((newbb.xmax - newbb.xmin)/2)/tan(fov/2) and cameraDistance2 = ((newbb.ymax - newbb.ymin)/2)/(tan(fov/2)xaspectRatio) and cameraDistance = max(cameraDistance1, cameraDistance2).

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt What i dont understand is why did i have to use aspect ratio for cameraDistance2? I expected aspectRatio for cameraDistance along x and not along y...but this calculation seems to work !!

Comment: The aspect ratio is not relative to the _fovy angle_, it is relative to the quad at the distance with the "height" relative to the said _fovy angle_. That's why you have to calculate your _fovx_ relative to a "distance" height and not to the _fovy_ angle.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can't translate directly the fovy (the one you give to setProjectionMatrixAsPerspective) to a fovx using the aspect ratio. This would assume that the projection is "curvy" but it's not, it's projected at a flat distance from the camera.

With this information, you have to find another way to compute the x-size, `distanceHorizontal`, in your situation.

Since you're using a bounding box, also keep in mind that this will only work when the camera is positioned in z aligned with the centre of the box, as the bounding box is axis-aligned.

```
// Assuming you fetch the aspectRatio and the fovy from the camera...
double aspectRatio = 1.0;
double fovy = degreeToRadian( 45.0 );
{
  double fovyDeg;
  double zNear; // discarded
  double zFar; // discarded
  camera->getProjectionMatrixAsPerspective( fovyDeg, aspectRatio, zNear, zFar );
  fovy = degreeToRadian( fovyDeg );
}


double halfSizeY = ((boundingBox.yMax - boundingBox.ymin) / 2.0);
double halfSizeX = ((boundingBox.xMax - boundingBox.xmin) / 2.0);

// Prevent a division by 0. 
if ( halfSizeX   == 0.0 ) halfSizeX   = 0.0001;
if ( aspectRatio == 0.0 ) aspectRatio = 0.0001;

double itemSizeRatio = halfSizeY / halfSizeX;
double distanceVertical   = halfSizeY / tan(fovy/2);
// The horizontal should be computed from the vertical value, and not from a fovx
double distanceHorizontal = distanceVertical * itemSizeRatio / aspectRatio;

cameraDistance = max(distanceVertical, distanceHorizontal);
```

I haven't tried this solution, but I once had to implement something along those lines. This logic seems to work on paper.

Comment: Isnt this calculation of distanceHorizontal similar to distanceHorizontal = ((boundingBox.xMax - boundingBox.xmin)/2.0)/ tan(fovx/2) where tan(fovx/2) = tan(fovy/2)*aspectRatio?. Also i edited the original question to include one more diagram, showing one more bounding box where i want to do an overview. Here as you can see, the bounding box extends mostly along z-axis and x-axis...would using the same fov"y" work in this case?